# Can we plot multiple location on waze map using waze API?

Tags: dictionary, waze

We are using google Map API for plotting multiple location in android mobile application.

We want to use Waze MAP instead of google Map. Is that possible to use waze map and plot locations on it through my android application.

Comment: Very broad question. SO intended to answer specific questions. As you can see my mad physicist answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I'll answer it anyway.

Waze provides a [Transport SDK](https://developers.google.com/waze/intro-transport), but that doesn't include a way to embed the Waze map into your own application.

So I'm afraid that what you are asking is not possible at this time. In case you are only having one person using the app at the same time, you could consider adding the points as favorites on one account and just sharing that account. But I don't think it's possible to share a Waze account on multiple phones, nor is it possible to export and import multiple favorites at the same time as far as I'm aware.